# Long question title displace welcome note

Tags: bug, status-completed

**Note: The issue is visible when not logged in on the site** - and the welcome note is displayed before the title.

Please do not downvote becase you just cannot see it

Welcome note here is a bit displaced by the long question title, when not logged it

[Tired of waiting for www.google-analytics.com -- can a browser setting "opt me out"?](https://superuser.com/questions/611370/tired-of-waiting-for-www-google-analytics-com-can-a-browser-setting-opt-me-o)

[image]

Comment: @animuson That is a completely different issue, it seems

Comment: It's the exact same issue, your end result is just slightly different.

Comment: @vasile - No. It is the same issue. Just close that welcome note.